# After factory reset Market keeps crashing on Galaxy S2 on ICS

Tags: google-play-store, samsung-galaxy-s-2, factory-reset

My phone was stuck in a bootloop, so I had to factory reset it. Now a new problem has arisen, which is that the Play Store is gone, and I am back at Market but it won't open and keeps crashing. Please tell me how to get the update from Android Market to the Google Play Store or at least get Android Market working.

- Phone Model: Samsung Galaxy S2  (I9100)
- Android version: 4.0.3 (ICS)

Comment: OS is ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH which was case even before factory reseting.

Answer (score 0):

Guess what I was running out of time and did factory reset again and din't do any of things told like clearing cache, data for market this time and within 15 minutes market got updated to Play store. 
Only change is I connected it over data than over wifi to internet.

Comment: This is the standard behavior... I can only speculate your initial factory reset did not complete properly or you did not finish the initial configuration wizard.

Comment: I did initial configuration correctly and complete but the Marketplace never opened and kept crashing. Which lead me to believe that high chance it won't update by itself.